# Python write string "1001101" as binary stream to file

Tags: python, string, file, binary, output

I have a very long string that is 1's and 0's.  It's about 12 32-bit assembly instructions.  I want to write this stream to a .bin file... but I don't want it to be in ASCII format.  I want just the 1's and 0's to be written to the file.  Any idea how to convert that and use .write to accomplish this?  Thank you!

Comment: No bin file is in ASCII format. But if you open your bin file in a text editor, surely some readable characters will show up, because the editor interprets the bytes as ASCII characters. There is basically no difference between the number 32 and a whitespace. It is just the way you are looking at it. In your case "1001101" will show up as "M".

Comment: Use [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters):

```
import struct
import numpy as np # for random string of ones and zeros

def chunks(s):
    for i in xrange(0, len(s), 32):
         yield s[i:i+32]

s =  ''.join(str(np.random.randint(2)) for x in xrange(32*2))
ints = (int(x, 2) for x in chunks(s)) # convert string from binary repr to integers
bins = (struct.pack('I', i) for i in ints) # pack to unsigned ints
```

output:

```
>>> s
'0000000000011111011101011001010111000000010110111100111110001001'
>>> ''.join(bins)
'\x95u\x1f\x00\x89\xcf[\xc0'
```

Note that `I` format is unsigned int in native format, you can specify byte order expicetely, with `>I` being big-endian int32, and `<I` little-endian (note reversed order of 4-byte sequences):

```
>>> bi_bins = (struct.pack('>I',  i) for i in ints)
>>> ''.join(bi_bins)
'\x00\x1fu\x95\xc0[\xcf\x89'
```

Comment: I was about to answer my own question... but you just did as well.  There is one issue with yours, it needs to be converted to big endian.  I checked it with xxd on the output, it works.  Thanks for the answer!  Here is my code that worked.
`i = 0
    while i < len(binaryStream):
        valueToWrite = int(binaryStream[i:i+32],2)
        binaryFile.write(struct.pack('>I', valueToWrite))
        i += 32`

Comment: @user2304751 yep, I didn't mention byte order, and was about to edit my answer, but you commented faster :) I'll add this for further reference.

Comment: @alko It's "endian", not "indian". Nothing to do with the citizens of the big subcontinent. The word stems from Gulliver's travels, as there was a dispute about how to peal an egg: at the big end or at the little end. Hence "big-endian" and "little-endian". One, two, three, four, five little-endians.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can write your binary string to a file, assuming that it is in 32-bit-integers and assuming that it uses the native endianess of your system:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.2

import struct

b = '011011100010000001101110010010010010000001100001011101100110111101110100011100100110010101100110011010010110111001100001001000000010000001110011011101010110110101100001011101000111010101101101001000000111001101100001011101000110010101100011011010010110010001100110001000000110010101110010011000010110110101110010011011110010111000101110001011100111001100101110001011100010111000101110'

with open ('out.bin', 'wb') as f:
    while b:
        int32 = int (b [:32], 2)
        b = b [32:]
        f.write (struct.pack ('I', int32) )
```

**About your ASCII concern**

If you open the output file `out.bin` in a text editor or if you `cat` it, the following shows up:

```
$ cat out.bin
In nova fert animus mutatas dicere formas.......
```

The fact that this is human readable text is fine and proper. It is pure coincidence that the original bitstream can be interpreted as ASCII. It is binary nonetheless.